# Can't get GSAP to return to initial state

Tags: animation, timeline, gsap

... and I've scoured the web for answers.
I boiled down the problem as much as I could in this jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/tko8rk5j/14/

There are 2 button, you click **Go** then **Boost**.
I'm trying to get the whole svg back to its initial position after the end of the **Boost** animation, so you can play the same sequence again and again.

I attempted various solutions suggested in other posts:

```
// tl.pause(0);
// tl.restart();
// tl.remove();
```

I also tried using the repeating TimeLineMax, but that just repeats the first animation sequence after the first click on Go button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure about what you're ultimately trying to do (which could greatly influence how I'd recommend building this effect), but here's a fork that I believe delivers the result you were asking for:

https://jsfiddle.net/2q1qrvty/7/

Your code was jumping back to the beginning before your animation even had a chance to run at all. Plus it was re-using the same timeline and constantly adding to it which isn't very efficient.

To make it go back to the beginning and stop as soon as it's done, just use an onComplete callback, like:

```
tl.eventCallback("onComplete", function() {
   tl.pause(0);
});
```

There are a bunch of other ways to do this, but I don't want to overwhelm you :)

You may have better luck asking your questions in the dedicated GSAP forums at https://greensock.com/forums/

Happy tweening!

Comment: Sorry not as straightforward as I thought... I did a really simple codepen here using the oncomplete callback, I don't see why it doesn't work: https://codepen.io/fvila/pen/NyVVdG?editors=1111 . The console log doesn't get triggered; does that mean the timelinelite never completes?

Comment: The problem in that codepen is that you call tl.pause(0) in the onComplete, but there is no "tl" variable declared anywhere, so it throws a JS error. The function does get called properly, though. You'll see that if you remove the improper tl reference. :)

Comment: Silly me! Thank you for your patience. https://codepen.io/fvila/pen/NyVVdG?editors=1111 now loops. Note that restart() works but not pause(0);

Comment: tl.pause(0) worked perfectly for me in your demo - I'm curious why you think it doesn't work. It jumps back to a time of 0 (the start) and pauses. Right?

Comment: It works now, in the codepen, thanks to the changes you suggested @Jack

Comment: No problem at all. Happy tweening!